# ValueError: Could not process parameters for MYSQL syntax

Tags: python, mysql

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host= 'localhost', user='root', passwd="barbie", db='data')

mycursor = mydb.cursor() #execute, fetch data act as a pointer
print("Connected to database")
query = ("select name , matric from users where username = %s")
username = 'shawn'
mycursor.execute(query, (username))
print ("Fetching single row")
record  = mycursor.fetchone
print (record)
```

The errors

[image]

Why do I get this kind of error? I only want to display the row.

The table from my database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is how you are passing the parameters to `execute`. `execute` takes an iterable (list/tuple) but you are passing a single value. The following 2 lines are equivalent

```
(username)
username
```

To make a tuple with only 1 element you need to add a comma (,)

```
mycursor.execute(query, (username, ))
```

Comment: why do i get the output 'Connected to database
Fetching single row
<bound method CMySQLCursor.fetchall of <mysql.connector.cursor_cext.CMySQLCursor object at 0x0000020DEDF33630>>' ?

Comment: i want to be able to display their name and matric

Comment: You need to call fetchone - `record = mycursor.fetchone()`